# CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria is not working after upgrading to sites 9.5 from 8.5 version

Tags: sites-9.5, brokerquery

We have two date fields (start and end) in component Metadata. We are displaying all the components with a start date less than the current server time and an end date is greater than the current server time.

Criteria.Add(new

```
CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria("Startfieldname",Datetime.MinValue,servertime,true)
Criteria.Add(new CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria("endfieldname",servertime,Datetime.MaxValue,false)
```

The above query works fine in the 8.5 environment but in 9.5, query results are not accurate. I guess it is not considering the "HH:mm:ss" while returning the results. I Checked custom_meta table and date value stored as it is in the Metadata field and it is not converted to UTC format.

Comment: are you using micro services , if so are you getting error on the content service logs , does the output for both 8.5 and 9.5 same are its different

Comment: We are facing the same issue and R&D is working on providing the hotfix for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004725) and run the profiler to get the query and see if you have the same problem if not you can reach out to support

Comment: Links get broken over time, so please put the relevant solution as the text for your answer.